# $F_{n}=\frac{1}{4}(F_{n-2}+F_{n}+F_{n+2})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_i$ be in the ith Fibonacci number, and let n be any positive integer $≥3$.
show that $F_{n}=\frac{1}{4}(F_{n-2}+F_{n}+F_{n+2})$

Not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Always mention that! Use the explicit form of the fibonacci sequence and just work out the right side until you obtain the left side.

Comment: Try starting with $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$

Answer (score 1):

$$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$$
$$F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}$$

$$\Longrightarrow F_{n+2}=F_{n-1}+2F_{n} $$

$$F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$

$$\Longrightarrow F_{n+2}=3F_{n}-F_{n-2} $$

Rearranging gives the required result:

$$F_{n}=\frac{1}{4}(F_{n-2}+F_{n}+F_{n+2})$$

Comment: In the second last step shouldn't it be $\Longrightarrow F_{n+2}=-F_{n-2}+3F_{n}$ instead of $\Longrightarrow F_{n+2}=F_{n-2}+3F_{n}$

Answer (score 0):

Well
$$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2},$$
$$F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}=2F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$
and
$$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n=(2F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})+(F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})$$
etc. These might be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: the characteristic polynomial of a sequence fulfilling $A_{n+2}=A_{n+1}+A_n$ is $p(x)=x^2-x-1$. The characteristic polynomial of a sequence fulfilling $B_n=\frac{1}{4}\left(B_{n-2}+B_n+B_{n+2}\right)$ is  $q(x)=x^4-3x^2+1$ and $p(x)$ is a divisor of $q(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to write the Fibonacci recursion that combines $F_{n}$, $F_{n+1}$ and $F_{n+2}$, having each one as a function of the other two.

$$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$$

$$F_{n+1}=F_{n+2}-F_{n}$$

$$F_{n}=F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}$$

Now shift them conveniently in such a way that we obtain three different expressions for $F_n$:

$$F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$

$$F_{n}=F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}$$

$$F_{n}=F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}$$

Sum them up so terms $F_{n\pm1}$ cancel, and we are almost done

$$3F_{n}=F_{n-2}+F_{n+2}$$

Finally, add $F_{n}$ at both sides and divide by $4$ to obtain the result.